# Not able to attach image using Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can anyone helpme out. I am not able to attach any image or anything using Browse button.

HTML snippet of the Browse button is as below:

```
input id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ITSNewIssue_file_upload" class="multi MultiFile-applied" type="file" name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain0TSNewIssue$file_upload" value=""
```

My Webdriver code is:

```
WebElement img = Driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ITSNewIssue_file_upload']"));
img.click();
img.sendKeys("Image");
```

I am reading the **Image** variable value passed in sendkeys through Excel file.

Any help at the earliest would be highly appreciated.

Thanks
Ankur Garg

Comment: Can you please try without "img.click();" step? and img.sendKeys(Image); - without double quote.

Comment: @Surya: i have tried that too....but still it doesnt work..:(

Comment: @ankur, Just happened to saw your comment for Juhi's answer. As I see, your problem is **retrieving data from Excelsheet**. Please add the code on how you are retrieving data , i.e., **file upload path** from the excelsheet. It will be easier to resolve then.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming **Image** has the path to the file you want to upload, say **"D:\\Image1.png"**, try this:

```
WebElement img = Driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ITSNewIssue_file_upload']"));

img.sendKeys(Image);
```

**Note:-** No need to do **img.click();** because, it will then open a window dialog box, which can't be handled by Selenium directly, and you will have to use **Sikuli/Autoit** for that.

Comment: i have tried this also...but it is not working in my case..:(

Answer (score 0):

No need to click on element.

Sample code given below :

WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.name("datafile"));
element.sendKeys("C:\Users\test\Desktop\testfile.jpg");

Answer (score 0):

Image uploading can not be done by sendKeys(). Either you will have to use Robot class or autoIt script
If you are choosing first option you can use following code:

```
    WebElement img = Driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ITSNewIssue_file_upload']"));        
         StringSelection ss = new StringSelection("Your file path");
         Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss,
         null);

         Robot robot = new Robot();
         robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
         robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
         robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
         robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
         robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
         robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
         robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
         robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: If i want to attach image by hardcoding the code the send keys is working perfectly fine but when i am reading through Excel than its not working..

Comment: When you click on image upload , browser will open the windows dialogue box and sendKeys will not work. Logically it should not work, I dont know how its working?